# Fragment Shader: get distance from fragment to bezier curve

Tags: python, glsl, pyglet, fragment-shader

Let's start with where I am;
[image: current state]

I have a fragment shader that generates this texture through FBO. I have almost all primitives I want, except for bezier curves.

My rather large fragment shader:

```
testfrag = """//fragment
uniform float thickness; //sets beam thickness
uniform float light; //sets beam intensity

uniform vec4 lines[200]; //pairs of lines; x1, y1, x2, y2
uniform vec3 circles[200]; //circles x,y,radius
uniform vec4 ellipses[200]; //ellipses x,y,width, heightmultiplication
uniform int ellipselength = 1; //amount of ellipses
uniform int linelength = 2; //amount of linepairs
uniform int circlelength = 1; //amount of circles


uniform vec2 polygons[200]; //polygon data, points in x,y. (0,0) points used as end marker
uniform int polylength; //amount of polygons


int i; //for counter variable 1
int i2; //for counter variable 2
float mindistance = 1.0; //distance from fragment to next segment

float P2L(in vec2 p, in vec2 lp1, in vec2 lp2) //distance point to line segment
{
  float squared = pow(distance(lp1, lp2), 2); //squared line length
  float t = dot(p - lp1, lp2 - lp1) / squared; //relative position in parellel to line
  if (t < 0.0) return distance(p, lp1); //before the line, get radius to point
  if (t > 1.0) return distance(p, lp2); //after the line, get radius to point
  return distance(p, lp1 + t * (lp2 - lp1)); //otherwise, get distance line to point
}
float P2C(in vec2 p, in vec3 circle) //point to circle
{
    return abs(distance(p, circle.xy)-circle.z); //euclidian distance - radius
}
float P2E(in vec2 p, in vec4 ellipse) //point to ellipse
{
    return abs(sqrt(pow(p.x-ellipse.x,2) + pow((p.y-ellipse.y)/ellipse.w, 2)) -ellipse.z); // similar to circle, with factor on height
}

bool PinPoly(in vec2 p, in int start, in int len) //test if point in polygon
{
  int i, j; 
  bool c = false;
  for (i = start, j = len-1+start; i < len+start; j = i++) {
    if ( ((polygons[i].y>p.y) != (polygons[j].y>p.y)) &&
     (p.x < (polygons[j].x-polygons[i].x) * (p.y-polygons[i].y) / (polygons[j].y-polygons[i].y) + polygons[i].x) )
       c = !c;
  }
  return c;
} //balls if I know how this works



void main()
{   

    vec2 pos = gl_TexCoord[0].xy; // get position on fbo
    for (i = 0; i < linelength; i++) //test lines
    {
        mindistance = min(mindistance, P2L(pos, lines[i].xy, lines[i].zw));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < circlelength; i++) //test circles
    {
        mindistance = min(mindistance, P2C(pos, circles[i]));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < ellipselength; i++) //test ellipses
    {
        mindistance = min(mindistance, P2E(pos, ellipses[i]));
    }
    i = 1;
    int first;
    while (i < polylength) //test polygons
    {
        //first for line segments
        first = i-1;
        while (polygons[i] != (0.0, 0.0))
        {
            mindistance = min(mindistance, P2L(pos, polygons[i-1], polygons[i]));
            i++;

        }

        mindistance = min(mindistance, P2L(pos, polygons[i-1], polygons[first]));
        if (PinPoly(pos, first, i-first)) //then test if it is inside a polygon
        {
            mindistance = 0.0;
        }
        i += 2; //jump over the (0,0) vec2

    }

    gl_FragColor = light*(1.0/thickness)*(thickness-mindistance).xxxx; //set color of fragment
}
"""
```

Which is called roughly like this in a pyglet environment:

```
def on_draw(self):
    if not self.inited:
        vert = shader.Shader(shader.texvertex)
        frag = shader.Shader(shader.testfrag)
        self.TexProgram = shader.Program([vert, frag])
        with self.TexProgram:
            self.TexProgram["lines[0]"] = (0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.5)
            self.TexProgram["lines[1]"] = (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
            self.TexProgram["circles[0]"] = (0.5, 0.5, 0.1)
            self.TexProgram["ellipses[0]"] = (0.75, 0.25, 0.1, 2.0) #x,y, width, multiplicator on height
            self.TexProgram["polygons[0]"] = (0.1, 0.9)
            self.TexProgram["polygons[1]"] = (0.2, 0.9)
            self.TexProgram["polygons[2]"] = (0.2, 1)
            self.TexProgram["polygons[3]"] = (0.1, 1)
            self.TexProgram["polygons[4]"] = (0,0)
            self.TexProgram["polygons[5]"] = (0.1, 0.1)
            self.TexProgram["polygons[6]"] = (0.2, 0.1)
            self.TexProgram["polygons[7]"] = (0.2, 0.2)
            self.TexProgram["polygons[8]"] = (0.1, 0.2)
            self.TexProgram["polygons[9]"] = (0,0)
            self.TexProgram["polylength"] = 8
            self.TexProgram["light"] = 1.05
            self.TexProgram["thickness"] = 0.02
        self.inited = True

    self.clear()
    else:
        with self.TexProgram:
            self.fbo.bind_texture()
            self.fbo.clear()
            t = (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
            x1 = 0
            x2 = w
            y1 = 0
            y2 = h

            glColor4d(1,1,1,1)
            glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D)
            glBegin(GL_QUADS)
            glTexCoord2d(t[0], t[1]); glVertex2d(x1, y1)
            glTexCoord2d(t[2], t[3]); glVertex2d(x2, y1)
            glTexCoord2d(t[4], t[5]); glVertex2d(x2, y2)
            glTexCoord2d(t[6], t[7]); glVertex2d(x1, y2)
            glEnd()
```

The bezier curves often have more than 3 points, everything is in 2D space.
The way I see it, there are 2 ways to solve this.

1:

```
Generate points on curve.
get closest curve point.
generate points around curve point.
get closest point of those.
rince and repeat last steps until satisfactory precision is reached.
```

2:
Come up with a formula/algorithm to get the distance analytically. I attempted this and found no solution for any number of bezier curve points, only for a constant amount.

I would prefer a solution to the second method.
I can come up with a solution for the first method on my own, but in case someone knows of any resources to look it up so I don't waste time could be helpful anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend computing the distance analytically for arbitrary Bezier curves, because  every point of the Bezier curve depends on every knot, the same is true for the distance to the curve. (Even without this your current implementation seems to be quite consuming and won't scale.)

I can recommend two ways to compute distance maps (or Voronoi diagrams) for arbitrary shapes:

1. [Fast computation of generalized Voronoi diagrams...](http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/VORONOI/) : for each line (segment) you draw a "tent" (two quads arranged like a roof) and render the scene from above - the depth buffer is your distance map. Beam thickness and intensity can be adapted in a shader or by adapting the tent height. For each point, you render a cone.
   Edit: the extra geometry could also be generated in a Geometry Shader.
2. [Jump Flooding](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~tants/jfa.html): For this, you need to setup a ping pong rendering scheme and render to multiple buffers. I skip the algorithm as it is a bit lengthy to explain, look at the paper.

Both algorithms work well for large number of shapes.